# How can I obtain the date based on geographical coordinates? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, date, mobile, datetime-format

I am making a weather application, and I have a simple P-tag which is populated with the date using JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<p id="date"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getDate() {
    var shortDate = document.getElementById("date");
    var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
        weekday: "long",
        month: "long",
        day: "numeric"
    });
    shortDate.innerHTML = today;
}
```

My issue is that it always presents the date where I am (which is understandable). Though when I physically change the latitude and longitude to locations with a different date in my JavaScript (such as Australia), it still uses the date where I am, and not that of the coordinates I have amended for the purpose of testing this.

I'm still learning JavaScript, but how can I overcome this to ensure my program uses the date of the different location? Or even using the timezone of the location? When I amended my JavaScript to Australia coordinate, it didn't show the date in Australia!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question! I had to use the offset provided by the API and multiply by 1000

```
let today = new Date(Date.now() + offset * 1000).toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
    weekday: "long",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric"
    });

shortDate.innerHTML = today;
```